# Foreach echo array returns 3 values for 1

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following strange problem, I cant solve it, my loop returns unique parts once, but the two parts I fill the array with before both loops, get used for every one of them. Hope you can help me.

```
$aBuild = array();
$part1 = "Test 1";
$part2 = "Test 2";  
$aBuild = array(1=> $part1, 2 => $part2);
```

Then I have a foreach loop getting data from database, in that same loop I do this:

```
$aBuild[$iNumber] = $sOtherParts;
```

Adding things to the array. At the end of this query foreach loop, i do this:

```
ksort($aBuild);

foreach($aBuild as $values)
{
    echo  $values;  
}
```

This echo's each $sOtherParts once, but for each of those, it adds the  $part1  and  $part2, to it:

Like this:

> Unique part
>   Test 1
>   Test 2
>   Another Unique part
>   Test 1
>   Test 2
>   Really Unique part
>   Test 1
>   Test 2
>   Ect.. Unique part
>   Test 1
>   Test 2

Comment: try `var_dump($aBuild);` to see what the values are and then iterate/echo

Comment: How is your `$sOtherElement` set?

Answer (score 1):

You should echo out your key as well. It's likely the following line may not be replacing data from your original array:

```
$aBuild[$iNumber] = $sOtherParts;
```

Try changing the foreach loop to print out your key:

```
ksort($aBuild);

foreach($aBuild as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br />\n";
}
```

Without seeing the actual code, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You need a newline at the end of the echo statement, as echo doesn't automatically provide one like echo in DOS or Bash etc.

Also, if your $iNumber var is just an incrementing variable, why not just use:

$aBuild[] = $sOtherParts;

Then you shouldn't need ksort.

Comment: Do you mean, with new line <br />? I need the iNumber to order the parts in the right way.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the problem of duplicate parts?

Comment: Well, not from the code above, coder, because when I run it it works fine. The only part I had to guess involved the addition of the extra parts from the SQL query, which I faked by doing my own foreach loop on another array and running the addition snippet you showed for each element to add these to the aBuild array. But it worked perfectly, and I didn't get duplicates. Can you let us know what version of PHP you're using, how you're calling it (via a webpage, or from the command line) and show us the code that does the query and adds to the aBuild array? The problem might be in there.

Comment: <?php

$aOtherParts = array(3 => 'three', 7 => 'seven', 5 => 'five');

$aBuild = array();
$part1 = "Test 1";
$part2 = "Test 2";
$aBuild = array(1=> $part1, 2 => $part2);

foreach ($aOtherParts as $iNumber => $sOtherParts)
        $aBuild[$iNumber] = $sOtherParts;

ksort($aBuild);

foreach($aBuild as $values)
{
    echo  $values . "\n";
}
?>